Converting pigpio code to Gpiod library python
I have the following code of pigpio library and I have to convert it's functionality using gpiod library. Where pigpio has a good documentation I can understand the working of previous code using that. But the problem arises when I try to convert it, the gpiod does not have a documentation at all (or I couldn't find one).
The following is the code of pigpio
import pigpio

relay_1 = 5
pi = pigpio.pi()
def setupGPIO():
    if not pi.connected:  # Check connected
        print("Not connected to PIGPIO Daemon")
        setupGPIO()
    else:
        print("Connected to PIGPIO Daemon")

        pi.set_pull_up_down(relay_1, pigpio.PUD_DOWN)
        cb1 = pi.callback(relay_1, pigpio.EITHER_EDGE, pinChange)

def pinChange(pin, state, t):
    if (state == 0):
        print('LOW', pin, str(t))
    else:
        print('HIGH', pin, str(t))
    lastPin = t # used somewhere else

    if (pin == interCom):
        some_func(state) 
    else:
        check_lights()


def check_lights(self):
    r1 = pi.read(relay_1)
    totals = r1
    print(f'totals != pinTotals {totals} {pinTotals}') 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    setupGPIO()

What I was able to achieve
import gpiod

relay_1 = 5  
def setupGPIO(self):
    print('setup gpio initiated')

    try:
        config = {
            relay_1: gpiod.LineSettings(
                direction=gpiod.line.Direction.INPUT,
                bias=gpiod.line.Bias.PULL_DOWN
            )
        }

        with gpiod.request_lines(
            "/dev/gpiochip4",
            consumer='gpio-setup',
            config=config
        ) as request:
            print('Connected to GPIO')

    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Failed to setup GPIO: {e}')
        setupGPIO()

    print('setup gpio executed')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    setupGPIO()

Do not know the correctness of this code but I did this and tested for blink test that was mentioned in one example.
If any one can help me convert this code that would be great, or if any one can guide me or provide some documentation that would really help. Thanks for any help in advance

Probably you can ask this on another site, but I have some experience in Raspberry Pi, so I'll try to help.

Not sure what your code is trying to achieve, but it has issues. e.g. setupGPIO() needs to return the request so you can act on the pin.  And you recurse on exceptions?  There are some examples in the gpiod source.  And you can generate the gpiod docs locally with python -m pydoc -p 1234 and pointing your browser at http://localhost:1234/gpiod.html.  I am looking at integrating the Python docs into the libgpiod readthedocs pages, but not there yet.

The watch_line_value.py example might be what you are after?

Thanks @LukeL, Will ask there too.
KentGibson as I said I do not have idea of working that much. But I think it is what I require. Will doo some study on the example you provided. Thanks Again both of you

(You need to split a comment and notify each user separately, like @KentGibson here)

Ok, will take care next time @0andriy
